# Android Developer taxes in the UK

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

I'm living in the UK and doing some after hours experiments with Android OS. Some of my apps started getting money. I still haven't entered my bank details in Merchant account, so every time after login I see a warning that earnings are postponed because of this. My question is should I and how do I pay taxes on these earnings which are around £100-500 per month. I do have full-time job so my company does all the tax work from my primary earnings. Maybe there is a way to convert these directly to Google Checkout or Paypal so I could spend them on Amazon?

Comment: I highly recommend setting up your self-employed status (and get UTR from HMRC). This could seem complicated but it's not! You are making a decent amount of money and who knows that with a little effort this could be your primary source of income! You could also create a separate business banking account (though it's not required)---HSBC has a free business banking for 18 months.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Legally you are obliged to pay income tax and possibly self-employed National Insurance contributions on these earnings - see [this page](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/incometax/correct-mistakes.htm) for details of how HMRC will handle this. You should [write to HMRC](http://search2.hmrc.gov.uk/kbroker/hmrc/contactus/search.ladv?sr=0&as=1&cs=ISO-8859-1&sc=hmrc&sf=&sm=0&nh=50&ha=34&tx0=49612&fl0=__dsid%3a&tx1=2037&raction=view) after the end of each tax year to inform them of the extra income - you may well end up having to complete a tax return, which is quite straightforward.